# Numbers to letters with logical sequence

Tags: php

I have this array which links numbers to letters at the moment like this:

1-26 = A-Z

But there is more, 27=AA and 28=AB etc...

so basically when I do this:

```
var_dump($array[2]); //shows B
var_dump($array[29]); //shows AC
```

Now this array I made myself but it's becoming way too long. Is there a way to actually get this going on till lets say 32? I know there is [chr](http://php.net/chr) but I dont think I can use this.

Is there an easier way to actually get this without using this way too long of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slower calculating it this way, but you can take advantage of the fact that PHP lets you increment letters in the same way as numbers, Perl style:

```
function excelColumnRange($number) {
    $character = 'A';
    while ($number > 1) {
        ++$character;
        --$number;
    }
    return $character;
}

var_dump(excelColumnRange(2));
var_dump(excelColumnRange(29));
```

Comment: Is this something you actually use or did you guess that I am using excel? Cause if you did, I am using excel and I'm impressed.

Comment: @Loko - similar to what I actually use, but as the author of PHPExcel, I do this kind of thing a lot..... PHPExcel itself uses a formula, and caches calculated values for performance; but I do use a variant on this method for iterating over a range of columns

Comment: `but as the author of PHPExcel` Cant get more authentic than that :)

Comment: @Rizier123 - I wouldn't normally use the loop for a simple lookup; but I do use that method for iterating over a range of columns.... recently started using Generators in my own code for it as well `function excelColumnRange($lower, $upper) {
    ++$upper;
    for ($i = $lower; $i != $upper; ++$i) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

foreach (excelColumnRange('A', 'CQ') as $column) {
    echo $column, PHP_EOL;
}`

Answer (score 1):

here is the code which you are looking for :

```
<?php 
    $start = "A";
    $max = 50;

    $result = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++) {
        $result[$i] = $start++;
    }

    print_r($result);
?>
```

Ref: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/01/php-strings-unusual-behaviour/

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Even without any loops. First I calculate how many times the alphabet (26) goes into the number. With this I define how many times it has to [`str_repleat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) A. Then I simply subtract this number and calculate the number in the alphabet with the number which is left.

```
<?php

    function numberToLetter($number) {
        $fullSets = (($num = floor(($number-1) / 26)) < 0 ? 0 : $num);
        return str_repeat("A", $fullSets) . (($v = ($number-$fullSets*26)) > 0 ? chr($v+64) : ""); 
    }

     echo numberToLetter(53);

?>
```

output:

```
AAA
```